How to get land cover data for North America into R
Specifically water and forests. I downloaded from mlrc but the file is 1.6gb. I only need a resolution of res=c(0.508,0.24).
Is there a way to extract the data only for this resolution? If not, is there any other way to get this into R?

You can use several sources, the simple way would be to use {geodata} package:
trees <- geodata::landcover(var = "trees", path = "~/Downloads/")
usa <- geodata::gadm(country = "US", path = "~/Downloads/")

For water use var = "water". Just continental USA for simplicity:
usa <- usa |>
  terra::subset(!usa$NAME_1 %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii"))

usa_trees <- terra::crop(trees, usa)

terra::plot(usa_trees)
terra::plot(usa, border = "white", add = TRUE)


The geodata provides land cover at 30 sec resolution. If better resolution is needed, you may use ESA World Cover set (I have described it), but then you have merge the tiles for NA and subset for tree cover and water.
Created on 2024-10-06 with reprex v2.1.0

This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!
